# How to disable Scrubbing in TVMLKit JS Player Class

Tags: swift, apple-tv, tvml

I am trying to stop users from scrubbing forward (skipping ads) in the TVMLKit Player class.

I have tried setting

player.interactiveOverlayDocument = null;

but the player still shows the Transport bar, and I am able to scrub forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be quite easy.

On the MediaItem Class which the Player Class uses to load the video, there is an attribute interstitials that accepts an array of [starttiem, duration] values.

```
var singleVideo = new MediaItem(mediaType, videourl);
var videoInterstitials = [];

videoInterstitials.push({
                            starttime: 50,
                            duration: 30
                        });
singleVideo.interstitials = videoInterstitials;
var videoList = new Playlist();
videoList.push(singleVideo);
var player = new Player();
player.playlist = videoList;
player.play();
```